# Change Text Color within a cell using OfficeWriter Excel

Tags: excel, officewriter

I am trying to change the font color for specific words with-in a cell.  I don't want to change all of the text to the color just specific words. I am using an OfficeWriter ExcelTemplate.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Excel before running the file through ExcelTemplate, or are you trying to do this in code using ExcelApplication or something?

Comment: I am trying to perform this color code change in Code using Office Writer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ExcelApplication to Post Process your OfficeWriter Template file.

You want to get a handle on what is referred to as a CharacterRun See the [OfficeWriter documentation](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/CharacterRun).

Your code would look something like:

```
ExcelTemplate xlt = new ExcelTemplate()

//Process Template

ExcelApplication xla = new ExcelApplication();
Workbook wb = xla.Open(xlt)
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];
Cell cellA1 = ws.Cells["A1"];
cellA1.Value = "Test";
CharacterRun charRun = cellA1.GetCharacters(0,5);
charRun.Font.Color = Color.Red
```

Answer (score 0):

In the formula bar, select the words you want to change the color of, then change the text color.